# Weird empty file on desktop

Tags: files

I have a weird empty file on my desktop called J20820.

If I try to delete it I get the following error message:

```
Error when getting information for file '/Desktop/J20820': No such file or directory
```

If I do a `ls -al` from terminal, it does not appear in the list of files.

Does anyone know what this file is? It seems a bit of a suspect (file) to me.

Comment: The filename may have invisible characters as part of the filename. In `terminal` try `sudo rm -i ~/Desktop/*J*` and confirming the the correct file is about to be deleted. If this works, please let me know, and I'll make it into an answer that you can vote/accept.

Comment: ps: before trying to delete the file, you might try `lsof | grep -i J20820` to see if you can determine what is creating the file. My commands may return no results if the app is no longer running.

Comment: Just if you're interested which characters are in the file: `ls -l ~Desktop | hd`.

Answer (score 2):

Your desktop is located at `~/Desktop`, also `$HOME/Desktop`. By using `/Desktop`, you're asking the search to start at the root of the filesystem tree, `/`.

You can use `file ~/Desktop/J20820`, but since you say it's an empty file that won't work.